# Optaplanner employee scheduler

Tags: jsp, maven, optaplanner

I'm trying to implement Employee and volunteer scheduler webapp using optaplanner, which all files do i need to import in webaction.jsp file. Also can i please know how to proceed to create web application using optaplanner.

so far i have created MySql database with 13000 employees data in it and created jsp login pages to Mysql database. now im struck with how to create schedules to employees in Mysql database. actually im seperating 300 employees each by a supervisor. so that in the schedule page we can select the supervisor and make schedules for those 300 employees under that supervisor.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways you can create a webapp in Java and use OptaPlanner in that webapp.
Take a look at the [JBoss developer guides](http://www.jboss.org/developer-materials). OptaPlanner is based on POJO's, so OptaPlanner doesn't care what techs you choose.

Some opinionated choices:

- I'd use JPA-Hibernate to connect to that MySql database
- JAXB-RestEasy to expose REST services
- Frontend either GWT or AngularJS. With some Twitter Bootstrap to make it pretty.
- CDI-Weld to tie it all together

Comment: Thank you, Also can i use the files in optaplanner or do i need to develop java files from scratch to get the schedlues. If i can reuse then can u please tell me how to do that, cause the examples in web-examples folder of optaplanner-master looks different to each other.